# Adding a product select attribute with a source in Magento 2.4

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.4, patch-data, data-patch

I've created a module to add a product attribute with a select input using a source for the options. I've used a data patch to add the attribute. I can see the patch in the `patch_list` table but it's not showing in the `eav_attribute` table after running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento cache:flush`.

`Example/ImageSize/Setup/Patch/Data/AddImageSizeAttribute.php`

```
<?php

namespace Example\ImageSize\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Example\ImageSize\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\ImageSizes;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface;
use Zend_Validate_Exception;

class AddImageSizeAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchVersionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * PatchInitial constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return AddImageSizeAttribute|void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws Zend_Validate_Exception
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            'image_size',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Image Size',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => ImageSizes::class,
                'default' => 'standard',
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'apply_to' => 'configurable',
                'group' => 'General',
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @return array|string[]
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getVersion(): string
    {
        return '0.0.1';
    }
}
```

`Example/ImageSize/Model/Product/Attribute/Source/ImageSizes.php`

```
<?php

namespace Example\ImageSize\Model\Product\Attribute\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\SourceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class ImageSizes extends AbstractSource implements OptionSourceInterface, SourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array|array[]|null
     */
    public function getAllOptions(): ?array
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = [
                [
                    'label' => __('Standard'),
                    'value' => 'standard'
                ],
                [
                    'label' => __('Large'),
                    'value' => 'large'
                ]
            ];
        }

        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

**Update**

I finally solved this by increasing the patch version number `0.0.1` to `0.0.2`, deleting the patch in `patch_list` table and running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento cache:flush`.

Answer (score 0):

**Step:1** Create setup file following path **{vendorname}/{modulename}/Setup/Patch/Data/CustomAttribute.php**

```
<?php

namespace {vendorname}\{modulename}\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class CustomAttribute implements DataPatchInterface {
    /**
     * ModuleDataSetupInterface
     *
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * EavSetupFactory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory          $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply() {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'product_temp_attribute', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Custom Atrribute',
            'input' => 'select',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '{vendorname}\{modulename}\Model\Config\Source\CustomAttributeOptions',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies() {
        return [];
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases() {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Step:-2 Create option file **{vendorname}/{modulename}/Model/Config/Source/CustomAttributeOptions.php**

```
<?php
namespace {vendorname}\{modulename}\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class CustomAttributeOptions extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * Get all options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (null === $this->_options) {
            $this->_options=[
                ['label' => __('Option 1'), 'value' => 1],
                ['label' => __('Option 2'), 'value' => 2],
                ['label' => __('Option 3'), 'value' => 3]
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Now run the **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** command and see the **eav_attribute** table.

Comment: I was looking to use a string instead of integer for the option values.

Comment: So you can change like that  ['label' => __('Option 1'), 'value' => "value_1"],